# Aiogram не запускается pre_checkout_query_handler

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Создаю инвойс, на устройстве открываю его, ввожу данные карты. После нажатия оплатить должен запускаться pre_checkout_query_handler, но он не запускается

Состояния не использую, на всякий случай пробовал запускать через state='*', ничего не изменилось.

```
@dp.pre_checkout_query_handler(lambda query: True)
async def pre_checkout_query(pre_checkout_q: types.PreCheckoutQuery):
    await bot.answer_pre_checkout_query(pre_checkout_q.id, ok=True)
```

Comment: Код, который ты прислал, выглядит правильно. Видимо, проблема не в нем. Возможно, другие хендлеры перехватывают твой запрос? Нужен полный код бота.